# "How wonderful it is that nobody need wait a single minute before starting to improve the world." --- is this grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar

It was a quote from Anne Frank. The sentence structure looks a little off, especially the "need wait" part.

Comment: No, it isn't. But it's a general reference question.

Comment: Yes, it is a (translated) quote from Anne Frank. No, it isn't "a little off"; it isn't "grammatically incorrect".